# switch extension toggle button

Tags: puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I'm working on automation project , and I need to know how to use puppeteer-Jest to check if the chrome extension is enabled or disabled?
if the extension is enabled run these steps , if not run other steps ?

I know that Java selenium has something like this :

```
enabledButton= driver.find_element_by_id("button-enabledButton")

if enabledButton.is_selected():
    //do stuff if selected
if else 
//run other steps
```